# Magento 2.1 - missing array field default value in configuration

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configuration, custom

I have a custom extension which adds new inputs to Magento's configuration. Some of the inputs are `arrayFields` and its defined in `system.xml` file as:

```
<field id="custom_ranking_product_attributes" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Ranking</label>
    <frontend_model>My\CustomModule\Model\Source\CustomRankingProduct</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
    <comment>
        <![CDATA[ Some comment ]]>
    </comment>
</field>
```

Class `My\CustomModule\Model\Source\CustomRankingProduct` is a child of `Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray`.

In `config.xml` file I have defined a default value for this input like:

```
<custom_ranking_product_attributes>a:1:{s:18:"_1427960305274_274";a:2:{s:9:"attribute";s:11:"ordered_qty";s:5:"order";s:4:"desc";}}</custom_ranking_product_attributes>
```

In Magento 2.0.* I can see the default value filled to the input:
[image: With default value]

But in Magento 2.1.* it's empty:
[image: No default value]

However, when I try to get the config value, the correct array is returned in both 2.0.* and 2.1.*.
Just 2.1.* doesn't display the default value so after the initial configuration save it becomes empty.

What can I do to have the default value correctly displayed even in Magento 2.1?

Comment: how to set validation for above fields in system.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write default value to database in data install script.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that solution, but I didn't manage to find any other solution. Thanks! ;)